# Devise spec - scoped views have no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), which I think is a great authentication tool for my rails 3.2 application. Testing it with rspec, however, isn't so easy.

Here is my problem. I have different user roles, one is `user` and the other one is `admin`. I have turned scoped views on by doing `config.scoped_views = true` inside my devise initializer and generated the views by running `rails generate devise:views admins`.

The following is my failing spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "admins/sessions/new" do
  before do
    render
  end

  it "renders the form to log in" do
    rendered.should have_selector("form", action: admin_session_path, method: "post")
  end
end
```

It gives me

```
expected following output to contain a
<form action='/admins/sign_in' method='post'/>
tag
```

because it actually gets

```
<form action="/users/sign_in" method="post">
```

and it renders a different form with only the default devise user inputs in the terminal.

This indicates that it is rendering the default devise user view instead of the actual admin view. However, the admin views do exist and the path in the spec description is correct. Like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461981/rspec-view-test-does-not-render-changes), I once had the same problem with `users` - but these have worked fine since the initializer and paths were set correctly.

I even visited the page in question in the browser inside my test environment and looked at the page's source code, which turned out to be correct. So I assume devise's scoped views are not having any effect in this spec? Do I need to tell devise there is more than one user scope? Do I have to do anything different inside the spec than usual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the rails server and making sure to have this in `initializers/devise.rb` solved the problem:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

Comment: config.scoped_views = true goes under initializers/devise.rb

Comment: You're right! Thanks for noticing. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this line to spec_helper?

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```